# Where to find featured/bounty questions?

Tags: support, bounty

I'm new here and I wonder where I could find the questions with a bounty.

On Stack Overflow, you can find them by clicking on "Featured Questions" when on a tag page but here it is not the case.

I'm asking that because I'm planning on setting a bounty on one of my question and would like to be sure it gained visibility and interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems , Featured tab are disabled till there is some question with bounty.  But you can access it through [this link](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=featured).

A bounty can be started on a question two days after the question was asked. And you have only one question which is not 2 days old yet. For more details on how bounty work, read below mention Meta post

[How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/182734)

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes I know how bounties work but wanted to be sure it would be seen :D. I think I have 3 hours left to set the bounty so as soon as I get there, bounty will be set. Thanks again for answering. :)

Comment: Happy to help...